# When MVC3 application Keep idle it redirect to Home page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have implemented application in MVC3 with razor, it working absolutely fine in my development server, after  deploying  it on serve(Use IIS7 with windows2008) if site keeps idle for 10 to 15 minutes, after that clicking on any link it redirect to Home Page.
   I have also set Session timeout on server.
please let me know how i can resolve this issue. Is this Session issue?

Comment: have you implemented any sort of login mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

First, set the machineKey in your web.config -- see http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey for a generator. This may solve your issue straight up.

If this doesn't resolve the issue, the cause could be several things. Your application could be being unloaded by IIS due to inactivity, or recycled due to excessive memory usage. Both these would terminate all sessions.  Another possibility is your authenticated session has expired, if you are authorizing users.

This idle period can be extended through IIS, if necessary. In IIS configuration manager, locate the Application Pool your application is in, right click it and choose 'Advanced Settings' then alter 'Idle Time-out (minutes)'.  Note that the default is 20 minutes, more than you are experiencing.

Verify it is not recycling due to excessive memory usage by watching the w3p process in Task Manager.  If you see your instance growing large, then disappearing, this is likely the cause.

Last possibly is if you are using Forms authentication and the ticket has expired, your web.config file may be directing people to home page.